# Glassfish/Java/JS: store image file to servlet and retrieve it to a web page

Tags: java, javascript, file-upload, glassfish, image-uploading

How to save the image on the servlet?
And how to send it back to a web page?

This servlet receives a request from JS with a file input (image).
I want to save the picture (maybe on a list -db not needed) and then servlet sends back a response with everything he received (together with the photo).

Is there any suggestion?
I tried unsuccessfully with this code:

```
 response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("</HEAD>\n");
    out.println("<BODY>\n" +                     
                "<TABLE>\n" +
                "<TR>\n" +
                "<TH>--Asked Infos--" +
                "<TH>--Your Input--");

    /*for typical inputs from the form */
    Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();                
    while( paramNames.hasMoreElements() ) 
    {
          String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
          out.println("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
          String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

          String paramValue = paramValues[0];
          if ( paramValue.length() == 0 ){
               /* .... store a default photo from servlet 'cause user didn't give file...*/
          }
          out.print(paramValue);

    }

    /* file input */
String fileName = request.getParameter("avatar");/*avatar is the file input name from JS*/       
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\"+fileName));
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  
    BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;) 
    {
            output.write(data);
    }

     out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to upload a file is creating a form with `<input type="file" name="avatar">`. For the actual upload inside the servlet one should better use an apache or Spring upload servlet filter. For that code search in the internet - *a good excercise.*

---

A link [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/fileupload-javaee6-annotation-for-servlets-filterslisteners-and-better-file-upload-support-in-javaee-6.html), for support in the newest JavaEE6 support (apache Geronimo server, but Glassfish should be the same). *Before JEE6 one needed extra code, a servlet filter.*

Comment: yes, the form contains the <input type="file" ...> as you said. I have found the way for Apache server, but I'm trying to do it now with Glassfish. I've searched in the internet, but most examples are for Apache. :/ Any suggestion?